# Anchor tag has :focus style applied on click

Tags: html, css, accessibility

I am new to web accessibility.

I applied the style for `a:focus` as

```
a:focus {
    outline: thin dotted;
    outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
    outline-offset: -1px;
}
```

Its working fine when I press Tab to go through anchor tag in the webpage, the problem is when I click anchor tag, this focus style also applied but I don't want.

Is there any way to solve it?

Comment: let me know how it goes and if it is a appropriate solution for you. Also, if you have any additional questions, PM me. I've been through the twists and turns of ADA more than once :)

Comment: When you say, "when I click", do you actually mean, "when the mouse hovers over the link"?

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe, mean mouse down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I have done in the past for accessibility was when tab is pressed to apply a css class to the body with javascript like `.keyboard-active` and to have the focus style only apply if that class is active.

```
.keyboard-active a:focus {
    outline: thin dotted;
    outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
    outline-offset: -1px;
}
```

and then when the user clicks the body with the mouse, have javascript remove that `.keyboard-active` class (so that non-keyboard users do not see that focus class any longer).

Works for me and also was accepted as a correct ADA solution.

If you happen to be using sass (only mentioning because many SO users confuse the two) then you can nest all of those ada styles inside like so:

```
.keyboard-active {
    /* styles */
    a {
        /* styles */
        &:focus {
            outline: thin dotted;
            outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
            outline-offset: -1px;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45093754/anchor-tag-has-focus-style-applied-on-click?noredirect=1#comment77730584_45093754), I think that you need to define a CSS rule for the `:active` state and that you don't need the extra class from [simplexity's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45093769/6002174).

Essentially, you need this type of CSS:

```
a:link { /* style rules for links in general */ }
a:visited { /* style rules for visited links */ }
a:hover { /* style rules for links on mouse hover */ }
a:focus {
  outline: thin dotted;
  outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
  outline-offset: -1px;
}
a:active { /* style rules for links that are being activated */ }
```

If you have the same styles for the hover state and the focus state, you can combine them with the selector `a:focus:hover`.

I am using the **Link-Visited-Hover-Focus-Active** ordering described in Eric Meyer's blogpost [Who Ordered the Link States?](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/06/11/who-ordered-the-link-states/).

See also [The user action pseudo-classes :hover, :active, and :focus](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#the-user-action-pseudo-classes-hover-act) in the W3C spec *Selectors Level 3*.